# MVC: Create relative path for routes outside contoller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, relative-url

I am working on MVC application.

For test I was generating url as follows

```
private string CreateUserConfirmationLink(string confirmationToken)
{
    return string.Format("http://localhost:14834/Account/RegisterConfirmation?Id={0}", confirmationToken);
}
```

Now that I've published my application locally for testing, I realized that path is

```
http://localhost/Appname/...
```

So, the url that I'm generating doesn't work anymore.
How do I generate the url that'll work for all the cases?

Is there some way to generate relative path and make it work?

PS: This method is in one of my repositories, not in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the "server" address of your action and then append the query string:

```
return string.Format(Url.Action("RegisterConfirmation", "Account")+"?Id={0}", confirmationToken);
```

or:

```
return string.Format(Url.Action("RegisterConfirmation", "Account", new {Id = confirmationToken });
```

and if you need a full absolute url, you can use this third version:

```
return string.Format(Url.Action("RegisterConfirmation", "Account", new {Id = confirmationToken }, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

If you need to generate the full url outside one of your controllers, use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme` instead of `Request.Url.Scheme`. In order to take advantage from `Url.Action`, if you call your `CreateUserConfirmationLink` method from one of your controllers (which I assume you do), you could modify the method to take the UrlHelper as input parameter:

```
private string CreateUserConfirmationLink(string confirmationToken, UrlHelper urlHelper)
{
    return string.Format(urlHelper.Action("RegisterConfirmation", "Account", new {Id = confirmationToken }, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
}
```

**Edit**: for .Net 4 and above, the UrlHelper can be instantiated from the current context:

```
private string CreateUserConfirmationLink(string confirmationToken)
{
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

    return string.Format(urlHelper.Action("RegisterConfirmation", "Account", new {Id = confirmationToken }, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
}
```

Comment: and this Url belongs to which namespace? Currently i get error saying `there is no definition for Action`. I tried `system.security.policy.url`

Comment: Also, I think i need a full absolute url because this is the url that i send to user to activate their account. But also, i couldn't figure out the namespace for reuqest.

Comment: Where is your `CreateUserConfirmationLink` method defined? Based on your comment I assume it's not in one of your controllers...

Comment: Its in one of my repositories.

Comment: I saw your edited answer for using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme` but what about the `Url.Action`. Can it be used outside controller?

Comment: The simplest way is to pass along the `UrlHelper`.

Comment: unfortunately it is not called from one of the contoller. I have a method called `GenerateEmail` in repository that calls this function. And that method(Generate URL) is called from controller.

Comment: If you're using .Net4 or above, you could try instantiating a new UrlHelper. If not, try sending the helper from your controller all the way to your `CreateUserConfirmationLink` method. I would use this as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private string CreateUserConfirmationLink(string confirmationToken)
    {
       return string.Format(Url.Action("RegisterConfirmation", "Account", new {Id = confirmationToken});

    }
```